# executing Python script in PHP and exchanging data between the two

Tags: php, python

Is it possible to run a Python script within PHP and transferring variables from each other ?

I have a class that scraps websites for data in a certain global way. i want to make it go a lot more specific and already have pythons scripts specific to several website.

I am looking for a way to incorporate those inside my class.

Is safe and reliable data transfer between the two even possible ? if so how difficult it is to get something like that going ?

Comment: it can be done, using the command line (cli) exec() etc

Comment: Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can generally communicate between languages by using common language formats, and using `stdin` and `stdout` to communicate the data.

**Example with PHP/Python using a shell argument to send the initial data via JSON**

PHP:

```
// This is the data you want to pass to Python
$data = array('as', 'df', 'gh');

// Execute the python script with the JSON data
$result = shell_exec('python /path/to/myScript.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));

// Decode the result
$resultData = json_decode($result, true);

// This will contain: array('status' => 'Yes!')
var_dump($resultData);
```

Python:

```
import sys, json

# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'status': 'Yes!'}

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: your php example looks pretty simple

Comment: There's nothing hard about it, no! As long as you stick with standard data structures (string, int, array, dictionary, boolean, float), this approach will let you pass anything you need.

Comment: Where it is supposed to be script.py? i got null in php page!

Comment: Can you also give example of sending data from python to php please?

Comment: it's the same of the answer

Comment: If you are experiencing the `NULL` return from the python script, it may mean that `escapeshellarg()` is taking the double quotes away from the encoded JSON, rendering it invalid JSON, therefore causing `json.loads()` to fail. Try using `base64_encode();` instead of `escapeshellarg();` in php and `import base64`/`base64.b64decode()` in python.

Also, don't forget to wrap your path in double quotes if it contains spaces `'python "path/that/has spaces/script.py" '` as was my case. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Brian: I was losing the double quotes in python without escapeshellarg(), and escapeshellarg() solved that problem. Still, thanks for mentioning base64, I will try that if I have more problems.

Comment: This was super helpful for a Python newbie. Here is the output I received: array(1) { ["status"]=> string(4) "Yes!" } - as expected. Thanks.

Comment: In my case on apache server installed python 3.6. escapeshellarg(); works well. not the escapeshellcmd(); it works but it hardcodes character sets

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for "interprocess communication" (IPC) - you could use something like XML-RPC, which basically lets you call a function in a remote process, and handles the translation of all the argument data-types between languages (so you could call a PHP function from Python, or vice versa - as long as the arguments are of [a supported type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#Data_types))

Python has a builtin [XML-RPC server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) and a [client](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html)

The [phpxmlrpc](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/) library has both a client and server

There are examples for both, [Python server and client](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example), and a [PHP client](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/doc-1.1/ch09s01.html) and [server](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/doc-1.1/ch05s05.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem and wanted to share my solution. (follows closely what Amadan suggests)

### python piece

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["php", path-to-my-php-script, input1])
```

---

you could also do: blah = input1 instead of just submitting an unnamed arg... and then use the $_GET['blah'].

### php piece

```
$blah = $argv[1];



if( isset($blah)){

    // do stuff with $blah

}else{
    throw new \Exception('No blah.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is running python as a subprocess and capturing its output, then parsing it.

```
$pythonoutput = `/usr/bin/env python pythoncode.py`;
```

Using JSON would probably help make it easy to both produce and parse in both languages, since it's standard and both languages support it (well, at least non-ancient versions do). In Python,

```
json.dumps(stuff)
```

and then in PHP

```
$stuff = json_decode($pythonoutput);
```

You could also explicitly save the data as files, or use sockets, or have many different ways to make this more efficient (and more complicated) depending on the exact scenario you need, but this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `escapeshellarg(json_encode($data))` is giving not exactly a json-formatted string, but something like { name : Carl , age : 23 }.
So in python i need to `.replace(' ', '"')` the whitespaces to get some real json and be able to cast the `json.loads(sys.argv[1])` on it.

The problem is, when someone enters a name with already whitespaces in it like "Ca rl".