# Pass form variables from PHP to Python (inside jumi in Joomla)

Tags: php, python, joomla, jumi

Is there a way for PHP to pass HTML form variables (POST) directly to a python script called with "passthru" in PHP without PHP having to know the variable names?

Can PHP pass the HTTP POST request to python so that i.e. the `cgi` module in python will read it like it was passed "from the web"?

Basic setup: Joomla CMS, with the jumi module.
NB! Python 2.4, PHP 5.3.3 on RedHat 5.9 - only standard packages.

One of the jumi applications is a python script which creates a form, and also handles the POST variables.

Reason: A lot more python knowledge in our shop, and the python script does a lot in the background.

In the jumi PHP script I have:

```
<?php
$var1 = $_REQUEST['myVar1'];
$var2 = $_REQUEST['myVar2'];
echo passthru('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/joomla/jumi/portal-ldap.py '.$myVar1.' '.$myVar2);
?>
```

The python scripts then uses `sys.arvg` to process these variables.

It works - by all means, but it also means that any additinal variables must be known to both scripts.

Is there a way for PHP to pass the form variables directly to the python script in a way so that the "cgi" module in Python can process the variables as it would if I ran the python script with a framework/cgi/mod_python/...?

Python handling form variables:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
var1 = form.getvalue("myVar1", "nothing")
var2 = form.getvalue("myVar2", "nothing")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely want to read the values through `cgi.FieldStorage`, you could run the python script on an HTTP server, preferably limiting its access to `localhost`. Executing the call over HTTP would also be a *lot* more secure than passing the parameters to `passthrough()` unparsed.

Alternatively, you could change your python script to use the [`getopt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) module, which makes it easier to define the argument in key-value pairs like this (paths omitted for brevity):

```
python portal-ldap.py --myvar1 nothing --myvar2 nothing
```

If you decide to keep using `passthgough()`, do remember to escape all the arguments with `escapeshellarg()`.

**Edit:** You could also `json_encode($_REQUEST)` and pass it as a parameter, then `json.loads()` it in Python to get the array as a dictionary.

Comment: It's desirable to keep it within Joomla/jumi - so setting up cgi/mod_python is not an issue in this case. Maybe in another project...

Comment: getopt is one of the things I'm considering. Since the number of variables _can_ vary, I thought it would be a "Good Thing"(Tm) to just let PHP pass the $_POST or $_REQUEST headers directly on in a way that Python would understand, but I can't seem to grok how this can be accomplished.

Comment: @sastorsl: You could try passing the request object as JSON, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up with json - which I guess is also a better way since the python program is now more re-usable also if it's run outside the "web".

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question to explain how I used the info I've gotten.

I must also add that I'm limited by using python 2.4 and (maybe not limited by) simplejson - since I'm on RedHat 5.9 in this project - and want/need to keep to the supplied packages. So I have web --> Joomla --> jumi --> php --> python --> backend...

Building on the answer and comments from Kaivosukeltaja and supporting articles [executing Python script in PHP and exchanging data between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047979/executing-python-script-in-php-and-exchanging-data-between-the-two) and http://pymotw.com/2/json/

In the jumi application / php-script I have put (amongst other things) the following to allow HTTP POST to be sent as a JSON object to my supporting python script.

```
echo passthru('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/joomla/jumi/ldap-script.py '. escapeshellarg(json_encode($_POST)))
```

Then, in the python script I use `sys.argv` to read the variable, and `simplejson` to map the json object from PHP to a python dictionary (heavily simplified):

```
import sys
import simplejson as json
myjson = sys.argv[1]
mydict = json.loads(myjson)
```

I can now test if my desired keys can be found:

```
if ( 'var1' in mydict):
    print mydict['var1']
```

The user posts to these variables in a simple form:

```
<form name="INPUT" action="" method="POST">
    MyVar1 <input type="number" name="var1">
    <input type=SUBMIT" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The avid reader will see that "var1" is referenced in most of these steps, while PHP isn't, don't have to be, aware of it.