# How to transfer data between Python and PHP

Tags: php, python, json, python-3.x

I have a Python script that outputs a bunch of text to PHP using `print` and `shell_exec()`. I also have to send a dictionary between the two, to store some script information. Here is a simplified version of my code:

### Python

```
import json

# Lots of code here

user_vars = {'money':player.money}
print(user_vars)
print(json.dumps(user_vars))
```

which outputs (in PHP):

```
{'money': 0} {"money": 0}
```

So the same thing, except JSON has double quotes.

### PHP

This is the code I would use if I wanted to use JSON (`print(json.dumps(user_vars))`, which outputs `{"money": 0}`, note double quotes) to transfer data:

```
<?php
$result = shell_exec('python JSONtest.py');
$resultData = json_decode($result, true);
echo $resultData["money"];
?>
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there some reason I should use `print(user_vars)` instead of
   `print(json.dumps(user_vars))`, or vice versa?
2. Is there some other way to transfer `user_vars`/`json.dumps(user_vars)` without it being seen in the final PHP page without having to dump them in an actual `.json` file? Or am I going about this problem in the wrong way?

My code was based on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047979/executing-python-script-in-php-and-exchanging-data-between-the-two).

Comment: JSON is a commonly-understood format that can be parsed and written by both PHP and Python, as well as many other languages. Python's `print()` might not even be reliably parseable by Python itself.

Comment: What would your recommend using instead of the `print()` command in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does the trick.

### Python

```
import json
data = {'fruit':['oranges', 'apples', 'peaches'], 'age':12}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

### PHP

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
echo $json_a['age']; # Note that 'fruit' doesn't work:
                     # PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/JSONtest.php on line 4
                     # Array
?>
```

This method only works with strings, but it does solve my problem, and I can get around not using lists/arrays.