# Dumping to JSON file not working properly in class/function

Tags: php, python, json

I am trying to transfer a dictionary from python using a function/class. I have already made a simple transfer, more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444585/php-writting-null-for-json-file-written-by-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441197/how-to-transfer-data-between-python-and-php).

So far I have the following functioning code which simply transfers the `data` dictionary from Python to PHP:

### Python (Basic Script)

**(Must run first for PHP to work)**

```
import sys, json, random
data = {'form_type':'default'}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

### PHP (Basic Script)

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
echo $json_a['form_type'];
?>
```

### Python (Main Script)

I have implemented this into my main PHP page, which works fine with the simple Python script. *However,* the advanced python script with lots of unrelated code is not functioning. These are the *first* lines of that code:

```
import dill
import random
import sys
import os
import json

restart = 'yes'
user_action = 'inventory'
pickle = 'rpg.pickle'

restart = sys.argv[1]
user_action = sys.argv[2]
pickle = sys.argv[3] + ".pickle"

if restart == "no" and os.path.isfile(pickle) == False:
    restart = "yes"

data = {'form_type':'potato'}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

# Lots of more code afterward
```

This code completely crashes when run by PHP, and the JSON file is not edited and no output is received by PHP. Any ideas why this is or is more information needed to answer this question?

Comment: why did you mix python with php?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please?

Comment: I mixed python with PHP because I am using Python for the processing, because it is the language I know best, and PHP for displaying information. If you want to know, it is a text adventure like Colossal Cave Adventure.

Comment: Fixed indentation.

Comment: how do you run the python from php?

Comment: Using the `shell_exec` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is the JSON read line in your python script.

It is not indented properly inside the read block.

Since the first program is just a snippet, it did not break the program.

But with the original program, due to indentation issue you are getting a huge error.

The corrected script follows.

**Python (Basic Script)**

```
import sys, json, random
data = {'form_type':'default'}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

**Python (Main Script)**

```
import dill
import random
import sys
import os
import json

restart = 'yes'
user_action = 'inventory'
pickle = 'rpg.pickle'

restart = sys.argv[1]
user_action = sys.argv[2]
pickle = sys.argv[3] + ".pickle"

if restart == "no" and os.path.isfile(pickle) == False:
    restart = "yes"

data = {'form_type':'potato'}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

# Lots of more code afterward
```

Comment: Why is the `with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:` below `data = {}`?

Comment: I fixed that, that error was not in my original script though -- it was a mistake in the formatting when I put it into Stack Overflow. This is exactly what I have.

Comment: My bad, It is a copy paste issue. Thanks for editing it.

Comment: No problem! Had the same problem with my question.

Comment: I tried the implementation myself and it worked for me. Please check it out and let me know if it works.

Also you can accept the answer if it helped you! Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to keep digging... I'll accept it once the problem is solved. Thank you for all the help though! You have an impressive increase in reputation since yesterday! :)

Comment: If you can share your code, I'll check if I can be of any help. and thanks, It was my first accepted answer!

Comment: Found out the problem, going to fix it tomorrow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463593/python-open-function-not-working-when-script-executed-by-shell-exec-in-php Good luck on Stack Overflow!