# Python open() function not working when script executed by shell_exec() in PHP

Tags: php, python, json, apache, file-io

I have a `open()` command in my Python script which opens the file `data.json` in my Apache serve running on Raspberry Pi in `w` mode. This script in turn is run by PHP using the `shell_exec` command. When the script is run alone, the Python code works. *However,* it does not function when run by PHP. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or is more information needed? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please note that I am currently not at my workstation, so I cannot provide ant snippets of code if they are needed.

Comment: I am assuming you have some kind of Linux distro running on your Pi. Does your Python file include a shebang line (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script/2429517)? I think that was a problem that I had some time ago, when a Python file wouldn't run from PHP on some kind of Linux server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... as I said previously, I’m currently not at my workstation, so I can’t try it out. Thing is, PHP could run it fine *until* I started using the open() function. - and yes, I am running Rasbian and no, I don’t have that line of code, so it might be the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a privilege issue, although I am not experienced enough with calling Python from php to know whether that could be an issue here.

Comment: I’ve chmod 777 * everything... so I don’t think that should be a problem. Well, unless data.json is not made read/write yet. I’ll check when I get back home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to user2693053 for solving this problem:

> Sounds like a privilege issue, although I am not experienced enough
>   with calling Python from php to know whether that could be an issue
>   here.

and yes, it is a privilege issue! I fixed the problem by doing the `sudo chmod 777 *` command in the `/var/www/html` directory.

Comment: It would be much more secure, if you create a new user group, which owns the files. In this group, is the user you are running the scripts with, and the httpd user. Rights of 777 are really unsecure.

Comment: Sorry about not responding sooner, I got a question ban for a couple of downvotes on my other posts, so I haven't been on Stack Overflow as much... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the relative or absolute path?

Try to use the absolute path and check what's your working directory.
I think you are starting the python script not in the directory you think you are. :)

Comment: I am using the relative path (just ‘data.json’ not ‘path/to/data.json’). P.S. I like your user name. ;)